# How do I run windows off another drive while keeping my documents/desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I currently have two hard drives in my computer.

The first hard drive(1tb) it is super slow when I run windows on it.

The second hard drive is fast but it only holds 320gb.

Is there a way to run windows on my second drive while keeping my documents and desktop on the first drive?

Edit: currently when I run windows off my second drive it is like I have a new computer there is nothing in my documents Or desktop

This is a quick example.

Current disk usage:

Disk 1 - 100%  (windows and documents/desktop)

Disk 2 - 0%

What I want disk usage:

Disk 1 - 50% (documents/desktop)

Disk2 - 50% (windows)

I don’t have enough money to buy a 1tb ssd.

Comment: tbh, I'd go for a 1TB SSD & keep the old spinning rust drive for backups.

Comment: Keep watching for sales and for prices to drop https://www.google.com/search?q=1TB+SSD&tbm=shop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you right-click Documents (Desktop, Music, Videos, etc.), Properties, Location (tab) & change it to the bigger/slower drive:

[image]

You can do this through local group policy as well, but that might be more complex than needed. You'll want to install programs to the bigger drive as well.